# How to add image in Custom ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to create this UI.

[Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtEVq.jpg)

In this ListView,There are 4 changes in  every list item-

1)SPECIAL OFFER(Image View)
2)Name(TextView)
3)Companylogo(ImageView)
4)Feature(TextView)

I want to show special offers image view in  only 1st list item and change name,company logo,Feature in every list item.

If I use R.drawable.img1 than error change Signature of Model string into int for image View and also get error in setImageResource line.
Can u tell me what should I place "?" in Models.add() line?

I have done this.

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static CustomAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Model> Models;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ls);
    Models = new ArrayList<>();
    Models.add(new Model("?", "PP AUTOMATIVES", "?", "Authorized"));
    Models.add(new Model("?", "CAR CARE MOTOR", "?", "MutliBrand"));
    Models.add(new Model("?", "CAR CARE MOTOR", "?", "MutliBrand"));
    Models.add(new Model("?", "CAR CARE MOTOR", "?", "MutliBrand"));
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(Models, getApplicationContext());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Model> dataSet;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Model> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Model dataModel = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtName = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.txtType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        viewHolder.txtVersion = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.version_number);
        viewHolder.info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feature);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    viewHolder.txtName.setImageResource((dataModel.getName()));
    viewHolder.txtType.setText(dataModel.getSpecialoffer());
    viewHolder.txtVersion.setImageResource(((dataModel.getCompanylogo())));
    viewHolder.info.setText(dataModel.getFeature());
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView txtName;
    TextView txtType;
    ImageView txtVersion;
    TextView info;
}
}
```

Model.java

```
 public class Model {
String specialoffer;
String name;
String companylogo;
String feature;

public Model(String specialoffer, String name, String companylogo, String feature) {
    this.specialoffer = specialoffer;
    this.name = name;
    this.companylogo = companylogo;
    this.feature = feature;
}

public String getSpecialoffer() {
    return specialoffer;
}

public void setSpecialoffer(String specialoffer) {
    this.specialoffer = specialoffer;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCompanylogo() {
    return companylogo;
}

public void setCompanylogo(String companylogo) {
    this.companylogo = companylogo;
}

public String getFeature() {
    return feature;
}

public void setFeature(String feature) {
    this.feature = feature;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your image url . then add string to model and use picasso

```
Picasso.
  with(context).
  load(imageurl).
  into(imageview);
```

If you want to use your drawables then you and use setImageResource(int)

> Model(int,string,string,string)

```
    Model.class
    Models.add(new Model(R.drawable.abc, "PP AUTOMATIVES", "?", "Authorized"));

    Adapter.class
    viewHolder.txtName.setImageResource((dataModel.getName()));
```

Comment: I want to use my drawable.How can I use setImageResource?Can u send me code please.

Comment: I want to show "abc" image in only 1st list.In next list item I don't want to use any image.You can check my UI.I don't  want to use offers image in next list.How I add data in Models.add(new Model()) for 1st item blank and use other 3 different item?